# jquery validator: when to clear custom error icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validator to validate user input. I am trying to figure out when should i clear the custom error icon displayed next to the invalid element. The code posted below keeps appending the error icon. I tried to clear it in `showErrors` event, but no luck.

```
 $("#form1").validate({
                onfocusout: false,
                onKeyUp: false,

                rules: {

                 txtDate:{
                    required: true
                 },
                 txtType:{                   
                      required: true
                 },
                 ddlTime:{                   
                      required: true
                 }
               },
               messages: {
                ddlTime: {                   
                      required: "Please select an option for Time"
                 },
                 txtDate:{
                    required: "<br>Please enter valid date"
                 },
                 txtType: {                   
                      required: "<br>Please Enter valid type"
                 }
               },
               errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.wrap("<li></li>").appendTo($("#dvErrorSummary")); 
                    $('<div class="errorIcon"></div>').insertAfter(element);
                  }
             });
```

This is how my css looks like:

```
label.error {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic
}

    .errors { color: red; }
    .errorIcon 
    { 
        background: url(../errorIcon.png); 
        width: 16px; 
        height: 16px;
        display:inline;

    }
```

This is how my HTML Looks Like:

```
<body>
<html>
<head runat="server"></head>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <ul id="dvErrorSummary" name="dvErrorSummary" class="errors"></ul>

             <select id="ddlTime" name="ddlTime" </select>
             <input id="txtDate" name="txtDate" />
             <input id="txtType" name="txtType" />

       </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the piece, where you are adding the error message container

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.wrap("<li></li>").appendTo($("#dvErrorSummary")); 
                    $('<div class="errorIcon"></div>').insertAfter(element);
                  }
```

May be use can check the length property to insert errorIcon only if the value is less than 1.

Comment: thats where the trick lies, you can wrap this div around another specific div with specific id or class to zero on the particular message. btw do you have a live link of your page

Comment: ok. i see what you are saying. This will help me to stop adding multiple error icons. But if the input is valid, how do i clear it?

Comment: IN that case you code we dont need to do anything as this condition will work only for length > 1, other this piece wil work $('<div class="errorIcon"></div>').insertAfter(element);
, that you already have in your code

Comment: thanks for your help. Figured it out. Ended up using highlight and unhighlight events and length condition worked there well.

Answer (score 0):

This what I did to solve this issue :)

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: '<i class = "icon-exclamation-sign"></i>'
});
```

I tried using the above method, but I was hacking away too much so realised that it can't be right. Hope this helps :)